# jQuery: Appended Element methods don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code where I append a notification to the notification container. I want to fade in the notification after it has been added but it tells me that the function is undefined, but jQuerys `hide` method works fine.

```
const notification = $(this.generateNotificationCode(text)).prependTo(this.container);
// works
notification.hide().fadeIn();

// notification.hide(...).fadeIn is not a function
notification.hide();
```

Comment: Can you share jsfiddle or code snippet?

Comment: You mean `notification.hide();` **works** but `notification.hide().fadeIn();` returns error: `notification.hide(...).fadeIn is not a function` ?!

Comment: @A.Wolff exactly, i tried to reproduce it in a js fiddle but the error does not happen there

Comment: @MaxTommyMitschke Ya because your issue comes from something else

Comment: Ah man, we bundled jQuery slim instead of the regular jQuery, i missed that. thanks anyway

Comment: @MaxTommyMitschke I was just posting new comment asking if you weren't using a customized jQuery version... I'm glad you have fixed your issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I bundled jQuery slim instead of jQuery - i missed that

Answer (score 0):

Instead use:

```
notification.fadeIn();
```

Comment: Wait, why that? Especially than fadein an already visible element won't get any effect

Comment: notification is the element you are trying to fade, so that's why you call the method on that variable

Comment: jQuery prototyped methods are chainable so it cannot be the issue here